# Why can't I use margin-top 0 on section and menu?

Tags: html, css, margins

I'm trying to figure it out why margin top "0" doesn't work, as you can see on the code there's a white space between menu and section, I can only fix it by using negative values which I don't want to... anyone can help me out with this?

```css
* {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
header {
    background-image: url("medimare5.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 318px 175px;
    width: 318px;
    height: 175px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
menu {
    background-color: #70acdd;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2%;
    border-radius: 2em 2em 0 0;
}
ul, li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 1%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
li:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FFF;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
section {
    background-color: #70acdd;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2%;
    margin-top: -1.7%;
    display: inline-block;
}
footer {
    background-color: #70acdd;
    padding: 2%;
    border-radius: 0 0 2em 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Medimare
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<header>
</header>
<menu>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Consultas</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Conócenos</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contacta</a></li>
</ul>
</menu>
<section>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
</section>
<footer>
<p>Medimare 2020 © Todos los derechos reservados.</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe I should start using divs? I don't know..

Thank you everyone!

Comment: quick fyi - except in some earlier versions of ie, `header`, `section`, `footer`, `article` etc act as exactly the same thing as a `div` - just these tags have better semantics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem when you set `margin-top: 0` on the `section` is that the `menu` has bottom margin. If you set `margin-bottom: 0` on the `menu`, it should work as you expect

Comment: Oh so I just need to use-margin-top: 0 on section and margin-bottom: 0 on menu? Now it worked and I don't know why it didn't work before.. Thank you.

Comment: @Quickpois0n according to the title of your question, because you seem to have tried `margin-top` on `menu`, and not `margin-bottom`, but I couldn't know :-)

Comment: maybe you are right.. I'm so dumb... thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this requires explanation

```
menu {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```